# Pewter tea container seal character translation (Characters identified: 榮製)

Tags: seal

Can someone please help me translate this I've literally spent five or six hours and can't find anything thank you so much in advance!

[image]

Comment: the character on the right is '荣' in seal script (篆体), i didn't recognize the one on the left

Comment: 榮製, read from right.

Answer (score 3):

Should be "榮製", reading from right.
Meaning might be "Produced honorably" or "Qualified produced"(a bit extended meaning)

Comment: Why did 山 disappear?

Comment: Do you mean the two "^^" at bottom-left corner?

Comment: No, I mean 山 in top-left corner. (For the record, I think your answer is correct. Just curios why is there 山 in 製.)

Comment: @AndriyMakukha there is no 山 in 製. See http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=399 for a rough idea of how shapes like the upper left of 製 changed into the modern form (the example given is 朱). This change applies to things like 牛, 生, etc.